# Angular 5 - passing data from one component to another when submit

Tags: angular, angular5

In Angular5, I want to pass a value from one component to another component (sibling). For this, I have created a common service as below:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

    private data = {};

    constructor() { }

    setOption(option, value) {
        this.data[option] = value;
    }

    getOption() {
        return this.data;
    }
}
```

In component#1, I wrote the following:

```
onSubmit(form: NgForm){
  this._dataService.setOption('image', form.value.image);
}
```

In component#2, I want to get the value and want to console it like:

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.sharedData = this._dataService.getOption();
 console.log(this.sharedData.image);
}
```

However, it shows `undefined` in console.

Comment: Is component#2 created after the onSubmit is being executed? If not, then obviously this will be the behaviour.

Comment: If `component2` is initalized before the submit, you can do it with a `Subject`. If `component2` is initialized after routing from `component1` to `component2`, the data shall be passed via the router.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle yes, the component#2 is initialized before component#1. Thanks. Can you put your comment as your answer?

Comment: @NiladriBanerjee-Uttarpara Julien Metral's answer is fine. This is how to do it with a `Subject`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use observable instead :

```
export class DataService {

    private data = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});
    // behavior subject will keep in mind the last value so if the parent
    // emit before the first component is mounted, it will not receive the value
    // subject would not that is the difference


   // private data = new Subject<any>(); <-- Arnaud Denoyelle's solution

    constructor() { }

    setOption(option, value) {
        const options = this.data.getValue();
        options[option] = value;
        this.data.next(options);
        // .next will emit a new value to every subscription
    }

    get option() {
        return this.data.asObservable();
    }
}
```

Use it like that :

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.sub = this._dataService.option.subscribe(data => {
     this.sharedData = data; // each time option will change, sharedData will too
     console.log(this.sharedData);
 });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
   this.sub.unsubscribe(); // clear to avoid memory leak
}
```

The component 1 will not change :

```
onSubmit(form: NgForm){
  this._dataService.setOption('image', form.value.image);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change `data` to be a `BehaviorSubject` or a `Subject` (if you don't need intial data ) like :

```
private data = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});
```

Then change your `setOption` and `getOption` methods to use it :

```
setOption(value){
    this.data.next(value);
}

getOption(): Observable<any>{
   return this.data.asObservable();
}
```

Then in component#2 subscribe to your Observable returned by `getOption` :

```
this._dataService.getOption()
.subscribe((data)=>{
    this.sharedData = data;
});
```

Just remember to unsubscribe from that Observable via `takeUntil` of rxjs or some other methods to avoid memory leak.